# Ordenar una lista de una lista de objetos

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

Estoy cargando desde mi aplicación el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "communication_management": [
    {
      "dgcustomer_management": [
        {
          "task_number": "0001506380",
          "next_date": "20210831",
          "task_subject": "PRIMERA GESTIÓN TLF 666666666",
          "collaborator_number": "00511818730",
          "collaborator_name": "PERICO EL DE LOS PALOTES",
          "assigned_office": "000",
          "branch_description": "SERVICIOS CENTRALES                               ",
          "open_date": "20190617",
          "comments": [
            "680645217"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dgcustomer_management": [
        {
          "task_number": "0001506391",
          "next_date": "20210427",
          "task_subject": "GESTIÓN DE PRUEBA DEL FONE 666666666",
          "collaborator_number": "00511818730",
          "collaborator_name": "PERICO EL DE LOS PALOTES",
          "assigned_office": "020",
          "branch_description": "MADRID                                          ",
          "open_date": "20210427",
          "comments": [
            "HOLA AQUÍ ESTAMOS SUFRIENDO LA SINCRO DE TENEO"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dgcustomer_management": [
        {
          "task_number": "0000003480",
          "next_date": "20210430",
          "task_subject": "Acción de venta ( AUTOS/MOTOS ) Contactar con FULANITA DE TAL Y TAL",
          "collaborator_number": "00511818730",
          "collaborator_name": "PERICO EL DE LOS PALOTES",
          "assigned_office": "076",
          "branch_description": "GUADALAJARA",
          "open_date": "20210427",
          "comments": [
            "hola y hola"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Estás son las clases DTO que utilizo para cargar los atributos de dicho JSON (no añado los métodos get y set y SCommunicationManagement es declarado como una lista de objetos en las demás clases):

```
public class SCommunicationManagement {
    
    private List<SDGCustomerManagement> DGcustomer_management;
```

y SDGCustomerManagement contiene lo siguiente:

```
public class SDGCustomerManagement {
    
    private String task_number;
    private String next_date;
    private String task_subject;
    private String collaborator_number;
    private String collaborator_name;
    private String assigned_office;
    private String branch_description;
    private String open_date;
    private List<String> comments;
```

Me gustaria ordenar en el JSON los "dgcustomer_management" por el atributo "task_number" de menor a mayor. Sé que existe un metodo como éste:

```
Collections.sort(salidaDatosGestionClienteDto, new Comparator<SDatosGestionClienteDGDto>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(SDatosGestionClienteDGDto c1, SDatosGestionClienteDGDto c2) {
                    return new Integer(c1.getNumeroGestion()).compareTo(new Integer(c2.getNumeroGestion()));
                }
            });
```

Pero al ser la lista de una lista, no sé cómo debería actuar.

¿Podéis ayudarme? Cualquier duda o aclaración decírmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: Entonces hay una Lista de *SCommunicationManagement* y  dentro de ésta hay una Lista de *SDGCustomerManagement* cada elemento de esta ultima lista tiene un número de tarea y hay  que ordenar las listas internas por este número.

Comment: Tanto la lista padre, como la lista hija

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de lograr tu objetivo, pero siguiendo tu idea:

- Usar un *forEach* para recorrer la lista externa.
- Para cada elemento de la lista externa usamos el getter para obtener la lista interna.
- Crear un Comparator para pasar como argumento al metodo **sort()**.

Ejemplo:

```
for( SComunicationManagement cme : comunicaciones) {
    Collections.sort(cme.getCostumers(), 
    Comparator.comparing( p -> Integer.valueOf( p.getTaskNumber())));
}
```

Donde:

**comunicaciones** es una lista de objetos *SCommunicationManagement*.

**cme** es un elemento de la lista externa de tipo *SCommunicationManagement*.

**Collections.sort** recibe dos parámetros:

1. una colección, en este caso una lista.

**cme.getCostumers()** utiliza el getter para obtener la lista interna, no se que nombre tiene así que hay que adaptarlo a el nombre correspondiente.

2. un Comparator que determina como ordenar.

**Comparator.comparing( p -> Integer.valueOf( p.getTaskNumber() ))**

esto retorna un Comparator que ordena según el orden natural de 'taskNumber' ( en tu caso task_number ) pasando el String a Integer en el proceso. Se puede utilizar otra sintaxis para crear el comparator (ver Alternativamente).

**p** representa un objeto de tipo *SDGCustomerManagement*

**Integer.valueOf()** pasa un String a Integer

**p.getTaskNumber()** es el getter para obtener el número de tarea.

**-> Alternativamente** se puede definir el Comparator antes

```
Comparator<SDGCustomerManagement> byTaskNumber = new Comparator<SDGCustomerManagement>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SDGCustomerManagement o1, SDGCustomerManagement o2) {
    // taskNumber es un String pasar a Integer
    Integer io1 = Integer.valueOf(o1.getTaskNumber());
    Integer io2 = Integer.valueOf(o2.getTaskNumber());  
    return Integer.compare(io1, io2);
  }
};
for( SComunicationManagement cme : comunicaciones) {
    Collections.sort(cme.getCostumers(), byTaskNumber);
}
```

También las listas tienen el método sort() por lo que se puede simplificar el código:

```
for( SComunicationManagement cme : comunicaciones) {
        cme.getCostumers().sort(byTaskNumber);
}
```

Comment: El problema es que me ordena sólo a nivel de la lista de SDGCustomerManagement y también quiero que me ordene a nivel de la lista de SComunicationManagement

Comment: En base a que criterio *SCommunicationManagement* no tiene otros campos en tu ejemplo.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta

Comment: Estas trabajando con una lista de objetos **SCommunicationManagement** y cada uno de estos objetos tiene una lista de **SDGCustomerManagement** ?  O estoy entendiendo mal.

Comment: Eso es. Quiero ordenar ambas listas por TaskNumber